# Progress bar progress color in android

Tags: android, progress, android-theme, android-progressbar

I am creating an app which has a progress bar as one of the components.

I want to customize the color of the progress bar with that of my device theme. I am unable to get through it.

The min level of my app is 11.
Following are the images. But I have given the color to the progress bar explicitly. But I want it that according to different devices theme, the color of the progress should also change.
[image]

[image]

E.g., in the images attached, the color of the tab selection and the progress bar progress is the same.

Comment: How are you trying to set the colour?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code...

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:dither="true"
    android:drawable="here set your gray image">// if possible so use 9-patch image
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg"/>

</layer-list>
```

seekbar_progress_bg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <clip>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="Here use your blue image"// if possible so use 9-patch images
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="false"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="left"
    />
    </clip>
</item>
 </layer-list>
```

please set background as seek_bar.xml in progressbar..

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am looking for something that can dynamically make use of the colors based on the theme of the device... e.g., making use of themes and styles. So is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) site to create a custom theme for you. Just download the folder and copy all of the files  into their proper res folder (don't replace because you'll lose all of your already made layouts and style as well as your values) and then set the style of the progress bar as well as any other element to the corresponding style within those files. I like this method over doing everything by hand because it saves time and energy for simple tasks like changing the general app theme as well as specific elements.

Comment: I am looking for something...that can generate the color dynamically according to the theme. e.g., making use of themes and styles. Is there anyway to get through this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm sure you've solved the problem but what you can do using my solution is create multiple themes using [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) site and then whenever the trigger to change the theme is triggered then you just have to change all the UI elements' style to the one you want.